# Specify the path of links with coordinates in gojs

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have just made a p&id (piping instrumentation diagram) map with **go.js** and I would like to get the exact coordinates of links.

For example, I want to divide the links to several spot that I would like to give them manual (I just want to make a specific path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the property `Link.points` is for. This property can be set, which is how tools like the LinkReshapingTool modify a Link.

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Link.html#points